# Headphone Amp Impedance Select Switch

Tags: amplifier, gain

I'm designing a headphone amplifier, and I'd like it to be compatible with both 32 ohm and 600 ohm headphones. Therefore, I figured I could introduce a switch which allows the user to change the gain of the stage depending on the type of headphones they are. This would work by breaking or making a connection to a resistor in the feedback loop. In the image below, this switch would be between R6 and R8.

However, I'm not sure if this is overkill or if it could introduce any issues in sound quality/noise. Therefore, I considered just setting the amplifier to high gain and accepting that the volume control (implemented in the diagram as R7/R10) would not be able to travel the full distance for lower impedance headphones.

I wanted to get some feedback from someone more experienced than me - is this overkill? Am I worried about nothing? Is there a better way to implement this? Any feedback is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Why do you need different amplifications for the two loads? The feedback loop should  take care of maintaining a constant voltage at the ouput, and judging from the datasheet, you can output 100mA with no problems. So you only need to take care of your feedback, because I see no capacitors in there, which may create problems -- not necessarily, but most likely. In case you're worried about different powers in the loads, then there's not much you can di about it, since 600/32=18.75, which is the factor by which you have to adjust the voltage\*current -- too high.

Comment: I want different amplifications for the different loads so that I can dissipate the same amount of power in both, about 100mW. This requires about 7.7Vrms for a 600 ohm load, but only about 1.8 for a 32 ohm load. However if I just set the gain so that the output is always 7.7Vrms, if I plug in a 32 ohm load and turn it up, it will draw too much current from the op amp.

Comment: Then your overall amplification (R10/R7) is transforming the whole thing into a comparator, the gain is unrealistic. You could use a single opamp and, in the feedback, add two series resistors, Ra and Rb: Ra gives you the 3V, Ra+Rb gives you the 11V. Add a switch across Rb and you're set. This is the basic idea. How you want to implement the amplifier, is up to you, there is a whole domain of audio amplifiers out there.

Comment: The whole purpose of R10 and R7 plus the other op amp is to implement the Baxandall active volume control

Comment: The gain is 10k/1m=1e4/1e-3=1e7, that's 10 million amplification. Whatever circuit you want to have, I have doubts this is the amplification you need, but, of course, I can be wrong, given the proper explanation.

Comment: See page 6-7 of [this document](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu034/tidu034.pdf).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77146/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-billy-kalfus).